# 'He is an expert in sth' or 'he is expert in sth'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which is right?

I am always confused with the articles.

I hear that in arabic, there is no such thing as articles.

Comment: there is a definite article in arabic (il - el - al) but no indefinite article, but I don't understand what that has to do with your question.

Comment: Both are acceptable. In *He is an expert*, *expert* is a noun; in *He is expert* it's an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct: the grammatical construction is different and they have slightly different meanings.

> He is expert in something.

No indefinite article (a/an) is present, so **expert** is an adjective that describes him. This sentence states that he **has or shows** a lot of knowledge or skill.

> He is an expert in something.

In this sentence, an indefinite article (a/an) is present, so expert is a noun. 
The meaning is that he **is a person** who has or shows a lot of knowledge or skill.

The term **an expert** implies not only that he is good at something, but also that he is **generally acknowledged to have** this knowledge or skill.

Comment: You could also say "He *has expertise* in something".